# User defined qualifiers

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I thought about a little language extension for C++ and wrote Draft for a proposal (http://pdfcast.org/pdf/user-defined-type-qualifiers-1).

The idea is, that a user can define qualifiers like const and volatile himself, for ensuring some what qualifies code (i.e. methods) only calls same qualified.

The question is if this would collide with any language rules or if I missed anything.

Comment: I'm not sure if you'll get much attention on SO for this kind of question. SO questions tend to be very specific and typically include source code (see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)). There's the [iso-cpp](http://isocpp.org/forums) website where the "Future Proposals" forum has the description: "Do you want to propose a new language or library feature and get early feedback on your idea before writing up a detailed proposal?".

Comment: *A side remark:* If your current notation is `fixed_point<24,12>` vs. `u_fixed_point<24,12>`, you could use tags or "policies" to simplify it: `fixed_point<signed, 24,12>` (in fact, I think I've even seen this somewhere before).

Comment: I agree with @DyP, this might be the wrong place to bring this in. Upvote for the topic, not asking it here ...

Comment: @Dyp thx, I opened a discussion there.
https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/std-proposals/sIdQagqIruk

Comment: You might find [Enforcing Code Feature Requirements in C++](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/codefeatures.html) interesting

Answer (score 1):

Not really on-topic for StackOverflow. But yeah, "user-defined type qualifiers" is a neat idea, and one with a long history. They're commonly used for taint analysis (i.e., making sure user-controlled and potentially malicious bits aren't used as if they were trusted bits; making sure all your HTML is properly escaped before you display it; that sort of thing).

http://www.cs.umd.edu/~jfoster/papers/toplas-quals.pdf has taint analysis as its main motivation, but also mentions *secure information flow* (i.e., making sure sensitive information such as cryptographic key bits don't leak out into the non-secure parts of the code).

That said, for most applications, "user-defined data types" suffice. You can almost always mechanically transform, e.g. `std::string [[tainted]] x` into `Tainted<std::string> x`.

```
Tainted<std::string> x;
cin >> x;  // unfortunately, this implicit conversion of Tainted<T>& to T&
           // is exactly what we want to avoid
```